# how do i put what is inputted with buttons through a function back to an index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

this is what ive got, the item pushes to the array when typed in to the input boxes and the button is clicked to submit, i just cant seem to get it displayed on the html not sure where ive went wrong

```
$( document ).ready ( readyNow );

let garage = [];

function readyNow() {
  console.log( 'JQ' );
  $( '#addCarButton' ).on( 'click', addCar )
} //end readyNow

function addCar() {
  console.log('in addCar');
  //get unser inputs
  //create new object
  let newCars = {
    year: $( '#yearInput' ).val(),
    make: $( '#makeInput' ).val(),
    model: $( '#modelInput' ).val()
  }
  //push the new car into the array
  garage.push( newCars );
  //empty inputs
  $( '#yearInput' ).val( '' );
  $( '#makeInput' ).val( '' );
  $( '#modelInput' ).val( '' );
}
console.log(garage);



function displayGarage(){
  console.log('in displayGarage');

  $('#garageOut ').append
      ( '<li> Year: ' + newCars.year +
             'Make: ' + newCars.make +
             'Model: ' + newCars.model +'</li>');
  }
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="scripts/jQuery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts/client.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

    <title>Week 6 Tier 1 Assignment</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h1><img src="images/logo.png" alt="noah's car garage"></h1>

      <h2>Please Enter your Year, Make, and Model: <span id="garageList"></span></h2>
    <input placeholder="Year" id="yearInput" />
    <input placeholder="Make" id="makeInput" />
    <input placeholder="Model" id="modelInput" />
    <button id= "addCarButton">Add Car</button>


    <h3>Garage:</h3>
<div id ="garageOut"></div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

please help, i can see that the array is outputted in the console when typed into the buttons but nothing shows up on my html, am i not sourcing it somehow? i have the id set to garageOut on a div on the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are not calling `displayGarage` after adding a new car.
2. Simply calling it is not enough, you need to pass a new car to it

```js
$(document).ready(readyNow);

let garage = [];

function readyNow() {
  console.log('JQ');
  $('#addCarButton').on('click', addCar)
} //end readyNow

function addCar() {
  console.log('in addCar');
  //get unser inputs
  //create new object
  let newCar = {
    year: $('#yearInput').val(),
    make: $('#makeInput').val(),
    model: $('#modelInput').val()
  }
  //push the new car into the array
  garage.push(newCar);
  //empty inputs
  $('#yearInput').val('');
  $('#makeInput').val('');
  $('#modelInput').val('');

  displayGarage(newCar); // NEW
}
console.log(garage);



function displayGarage(newCar) { // NEW
  console.log('in displayGarage');

  $('#garageOut ').append('<li> Year: ' + newCar.year +
    'Make: ' + newCar.make +
    'Model: ' + newCar.model + '</li>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="scripts/jQuery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="scripts/client.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

  <title>Week 6 Tier 1 Assignment</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1><img src="images/logo.png" alt="noah's car garage"></h1>

  <h2>Please Enter your Year, Make, and Model: <span id="garageList"></span></h2>
  <input placeholder="Year" id="yearInput" />
  <input placeholder="Make" id="makeInput" />
  <input placeholder="Model" id="modelInput" />
  <button id="addCarButton">Add Car</button>


  <h3>Garage:</h3>
  <div id="garageOut"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hey man thanks so much for the help! I have another question im working on i think ill be able to do it but, if you have the time here it is.. thanks so much again!   I need to basically not allow it to be entered if one of the fields are left blank

Comment: Then you need to modify `addCar` function, so it checks whether a car with such parameters already exists in `garage`, and adds a new car only if it does not exist there. If this comment is not enough, please feel free to copy my code and create a new question on SO :)

Comment: am i able to add something with the same parameters but if one of the fields are left blank when putting them in, it can maybe console log out that the field was left blank